# Laravel - Using Where Clause with If Statement and Parameter

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel Query with where clause statement and a parameter in it. The $plan coming from the source is string and the values are:

> Daily, Weekly, Monthly, Wallet

but the value of $plan in the destination, users table ($users) are:
1,2,3,4

Parameter Source:

```
        @foreach($billings as $key => $billing)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('revenueDetail',$billing->plan) }}">{{ $billing->plan }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $billing->total_plans }}</td>
                <td>{{ $billing->total_amount }}</td>
            </tr>
            
        @endforeach
            <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                {{ $billings->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>
```

Controller: Query

```
    public function revenueDetail($plan = null)
    {
    $revenuedetails = DB::table("users")
                     ->select(
                       "users.username", 
                       DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as subscription_date")
                     )        
                     ->where('users.plan', $plan)
                     ->get();            
    }
```

What I want to achieve is that, in the where clause in revenueDetail() function, if:

> $plan = Daily then users.plan = 1
>
> $plan = Weekly then users.plan = 2
>
> $plan = Monthly then users.plan = 3
>
> $plan = Wallet then users.plan = 4

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on last sentences, i assume you need to map Daily string which == 1

```
protected static $type = [
    'Daily' => 1,
    'Weekly' => 2,
    'Montly' => 3,
]
```

then

```
public function revenueDetail($plan = null)
{
    $revenuedetails = DB::table("users")
        ->select("users.username", DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as subscription_date"))
        ->where('users.plan', self::$type[$plan] ?? null) // ?? will escape exception if $plan is null
        ->get();          
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the **protected static $type**   in the project. Controller of Model

Answer (score 0):

From view user should send id instead of value. However if u want to send value you should ask plans table for id of value u send. I recommend to store plans in cache. Another solution is to make class with Constans like your plans (if u dont want to extend it in the future)